# Displaying a message after successful uninstall in a VS2010 deployment project?

Tags: visual-studio, visual-studio-2010, uninstallation, setup-deployment

My VS2010 setup project works OK, but the uninstall process is completely non-interactive. It displays a progress window like the one below, then it vanishes with no feedback to the user. The user interface editor in VS2010 has only trees for "Install" and "Administrative Install", not for "Uninstall".

[image]

How can I display a MsgBox saying "[Product] has been successfully uninstalled" after the uninstall is completed?

Answer (score 2):

A simple solution is to add a Commit [custom action](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa368066%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) and condition it with:

```
REMOVE = "ALL"
```

Another approach is to set the [ARPNOREMOVE](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa367591%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) property in your MSI. In this case the Control Panel Programs and Features applet will show only the Change option, which uses full UI. The Uninstall option which uses basic UI will not be visible.

Comment: Can you please specify exactly how to add a condition to commit custom action?